# Optimizing query in Postgresql for group by and inner join using an index

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need some help with Postgresql 9.6 regarding performance.
A very simple example of the tables I have are as follows

```
CREATE TABLE invoice
(
   id bigserial primary key,
   some_field character varying(200)
);

CREATE TABLE invoice_item
(
    id serial primary key,
    invoice_id bigint,
    article_number character varying(50),
    quantity numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT invoice_item_fk FOREIGN KEY (invoice_id)
      REFERENCES invoice (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION   
);
CREATE INDEX invoice_some_field_idx ON invoice (some_field);

CREATE INDEX invoice_item_article_number_idx ON invoice_item (article_number);
```

I used around 500 000 rows in invoice table and 1.5 million in invoice_item.

Running the following query is really fast

```
SELECT ii.article_number,
       SUM(ii.quantity)
FROM invoice i INNER JOIN
     invoice_item ii
     ON i.id = ii.invoice_id
GROUP BY ii.article_number;
```

With index on article_number, the query goes from ~7 seconds to ~55 ms.

Now the problem is when using group by on a column from the parent table.

```
SELECT i.some_field, SUM(ii.quantity)
FROM invoice i INNER JOIN
     invoice_item ii
     ON i.id = ii.invoice_id
GROUP BY i.some_field;
```

This query will take the same amount of time (~5 seconds) regardless if there is an index on some_field.

I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here.

--- EDIT ----

I'm quite new to this query planning and of course, when doing more testing on tables above, I got very different results compared the actual code.

Here are the actual table definitions

```
CREATE TABLE receipt2
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  version bigint NOT NULL,
  store_number integer NOT NULL,
  address1 character varying(200),
  date_created timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  round_off numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  date_created_by_cash_register timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  address2 character varying(200),
  receipt_number integer NOT NULL,
  application_version character varying(50),
  control_box_serial_number_original character varying(200),
  last_updated timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
  cash_register_user_id uuid NOT NULL,
  control_code_copy character varying(200),
  cash_register_number integer NOT NULL,
  control_code_original character varying(200),
  zip_code character varying(50),
  receipt_footer character varying(20000),
  phone_number character varying(50),
  control_box_serial_number_copy character varying(200),
  corporate_identity character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  city character varying(200),
  money_back numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  number_of_copies_printed integer NOT NULL,
  cash_register_user_username character varying(50) NOT NULL,
  company_name character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  email character varying(200),
  website character varying(200),
  CONSTRAINT receipt2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT uk9f6f61365739562846c491f21efb UNIQUE (corporate_identity, store_number, cash_register_number, receipt_number)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX receipt2_cash_register_user_id_idx
  ON receipt2 USING btree (cash_register_user_id);

CREATE INDEX receipt2_date_created_by_cash_register_idx
  ON receipt2 USING btree (date_created_by_cash_register);

CREATE INDEX receipt2_store_number_idx
  ON receipt2 USING btree (store_number);

CREATE INDEX receipt2corpidx
  ON receipt2 USING btree (corporate_identity COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE INDEX receipt2corpstoreidx
  ON receipt2 USING btree (store_number, corporate_identity COLLATE pg_catalog."default");

CREATE TABLE receipt_item2
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  version bigint NOT NULL,
  cost_excluding_vat numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  account_number integer,
  receipt_item_type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  article_group_id uuid,
  supplier_number integer,
  purchase_price_excluding_vat numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  receipt_id bigint NOT NULL,
  text character varying(20000),
  promotion_id uuid,
  price_including_vat numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  discount_type character varying(255) NOT NULL,
  profit_excluding_vat numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  price_excluding_vat numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  discount_amount_including_vat numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  article_type character varying(255),
  article_number character varying(50),
  cost_including_vat numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  purchase_cost_excluding_vat numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  hidden boolean NOT NULL,
  row_index integer NOT NULL,
  quantity numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  discount numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  discount_amount_excluding_vat numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  description character varying(200),
  vat numeric(19,2) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT receipt_item2_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT fksohgmt8ntavcgj10ha2duc8lb FOREIGN KEY (receipt_id)
      REFERENCES receipt2 (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE INDEX receipt_item2_article_number_idx
  ON receipt_item2 USING btree (article_number COLLATE pg_catalog."default");
```

Query 1 with explain. This will be very fast. Around 55ms.

```
SELECT 
  article_number,
  sum(quantity) AS "quantity",
  sum(cost_excluding_vat) AS "costExcludingVat",
  sum(cost_including_vat) AS "costIncludingVat",
  sum(purchase_cost_excluding_vat) AS "purchaseCostExcludingVat",
  sum(profit_excluding_vat) AS "profitExcludingVat"
FROM receipt2 receipt INNER JOIN receipt_item2 receipt_item ON receipt.id = receipt_item.receipt_id
WHERE 
  date_created_by_cash_register BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
  AND receipt_item_type = 'ARTICLE'
GROUP BY article_number
LIMIT 100;


"Limit  (cost=0.85..4821.60 rows=100 width=167)"
"  ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=0.85..948001.24 rows=19665 width=167)"
"        Group Key: receipt_item.article_number"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.85..925058.77 rows=1500000 width=35)"
"              ->  Index Scan using receipt_item2_article_number_idx on receipt_item2 receipt_item  (cost=0.43..196242.77 rows=1500000 width=43)"
"                    Filter: ((receipt_item_type)::text = 'ARTICLE'::text)"
"              ->  Index Scan using receipt2_pkey on receipt2 receipt  (cost=0.42..0.48 rows=1 width=4)"
"                    Index Cond: (id = receipt_item.receipt_id)"
"                    Filter: ((date_created_by_cash_register >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date_created_by_cash_register <= '2017-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))"
```

Query 2 with explain. This query will take 2.3 seconds regardless if there is an index on cash_register_user_id or nor.

```
SELECT 
  cash_register_user_id AS "userId",
  sum(quantity) AS "quantity",
  sum(cost_excluding_vat) AS "costExcludingVat",
  sum(cost_including_vat) AS "costIncludingVat",
  sum(purchase_cost_excluding_vat) AS "purchaseCostExcludingVat",
  sum(profit_excluding_vat) AS "profitExcludingVat"
FROM receipt2 receipt INNER JOIN receipt_item2 receipt_item ON receipt.id = receipt_id
WHERE 
  date_created_by_cash_register BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2017-12-31'
  AND receipt_item_type = 'ARTICLE'
  AND receipt.store_number = 1
GROUP BY cash_register_user_id
LIMIT 100;

"Limit  (cost=154761.00..154761.45 rows=20 width=176)"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=154761.00..154761.45 rows=20 width=176)"
"        Group Key: receipt.cash_register_user_id"
"        ->  Hash Join  (cost=28135.00..132261.00 rows=1500000 width=44)"
"              Hash Cond: (receipt_item.receipt_id = receipt.id)"
"              ->  Seq Scan on receipt_item2 receipt_item  (cost=0.00..57133.00 rows=1500000 width=36)"
"                    Filter: ((receipt_item_type)::text = 'ARTICLE'::text)"
"              ->  Hash  (cost=18955.00..18955.00 rows=500000 width=20)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on receipt2 receipt  (cost=0.00..18955.00 rows=500000 width=20)"
"                          Filter: ((date_created_by_cash_register >= '2017-01-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date_created_by_cash_register <= '2017-12-31 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (store_number = 1))"
```

A bit of topic for this question but whatever comes out of this, the next problem would be to have it sorted. The holy grail is to be able to sort on the aggregated values quantity, cost etc...

Comment: The obvious thing that's missing is `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` output for both queries so that we can see what is going on.

Comment: And how many distict values for `article_number` are there? (what is its cardinality?)

Comment: @wildplasser , I used 20 000 different ones but in production there might be up to 100 000.

Comment: Which implies that you are storing all these bulky strings 1.5M/100K := 15 times, on average. (and probably the same goes for the other low-cardinality fields). My suggestion is to squeeze some of these out into separate tables, and refer to these via (integer) FK(s).

Comment: So you would say it might be better if receipt_item would have a fk to an receipt_item_article table and join that table in the query?

Comment: Yes, and it could also contain the fields that depend on it, such as the category, type, etc. (Discount is probably different, price could be a bit harder, if it varies over time)

Answer (score 0):

The real answer is to look at the execution plans.  But this might give you an idea of what might be happening.  The first query can essentially be rewritten as:

```
SELECT ii.article_number, SUM(ii.quantity)
FROM invoice_item ii
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM invoice i WHERE i.id = ii.invoice_id)
GROUP BY ii.article_number;
```

This, in turn, can be resolved by scanning the index on `invoice_item(article_number)`.  The information can be compiled for each group, with no hashing or sorting -- just a lookup for each row.

There is no equivalent way in the second query to avoid doing work for the aggregation.